How to find and replace in Violentmonkey editor
I have a script I made but I needed to make some edits. I need to replace all the "console.log(" in the script. My script is about 5k lines long and there's way to many "console.log(" for me to replace manually. Is there a way or a plugin I can use to find and replace all the "console.log(" with "//console.log(" in Violentmonkey? Tanks.
I've looked all through Violentmonkey didn't find anything, researched some stuff but couldn't find anything. :/

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
